# Retrive Only Presentation file from Google Drive using Google drive SDK using .net

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to retrieve only Presentation file from Google Drive so I am using following code :

```
PresentationsQuery query =new PresentationsQuery()
DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);

foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
```

but I am not getting any Presentation file in result thow files available there
and please not IsPresentation Property also return false of that document.

Can any one help me for same? and please tell me that when this IsPresentation property return true.

Answer (score 0):

PresentationsQuery is the old Gdata API. Are you sure you don't want to use the new Drive SDK. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: How Can i get Only Presentation from Google drive using this new  Drive SDK.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list   
.
.
.

    GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=mimeType+%3D+'application%2Fvnd.google-apps.presentation'&key={YOUR_API_KEY}